# No NSTableViewDelegate methods are ever called in my document-based app. Why?

Tags: objective-c, macos, delegates, nstableview

I'm creating an `NSTableView` programatically. `numberOfRowsInTableView` is the only method that gets called when I assign the `delegate` and `dataSource`. The `NSTableView` remains blank and empty. What am I doing wrong?

in myDocument.m:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    NSTableView *tableView = [NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)];
    // I've tried putting the delegate before the datasource. No change.
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;

    // I've tried adding the table before assigning the delegate/datasource. No change.
    [aController.window.contentView addSubview:tableView];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{

    NSLog(@"making view for table...");

    NSBox *box = [[NSBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    box.borderColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    box.borderWidth = 10;
    return box;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    NSLog(@"getting data...");
    return @{ @"myKey": @"myValue" };
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    NSLog(@"getting count...");
    return 2;
}
```

`numberOfRowsInTableView` is the only thing that get's called. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your .h implement the delegate and datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You table view doesn't contain any columns and therefore doesn't call the `viewForColumn:` delegate method.

Replace your initialization code in `windowControllerDidLoadNib` with the following and your delegate methods will get called:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    NSTableView *tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)];
    [tableView addTableColumn:[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MyColumn"]];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [aController.window.contentView addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Probably you can use Interface Builder to configure & layout your tableview.

Comment: I don't want to use Interface Builder at all. Will this work equally well with completely programmatic NSTableViews?

Comment: Yes - With the above code your delegate methods will be called at least. But you'll have to add resizing masks or autolayout constraints to position and layout your table view.

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing it out now. I'm not directly using resizing masks or autolayout at all either. For me, using [ReactiveCocoaLayout](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaLayout) is easier for all sizing and layout purposes.